# Send email from Ruby program with TLS

Tags: ruby, email

I am trying to send an email from a Ruby program.  The smtp server is an Exchange 2007 server that requires me to login to send the email.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/smtp'

msgstr = "Test email."

smtp = Net::SMTP.start('smtp.server.com', 587, 
  'mail.server.com', 'username', 'password', :login) do |smtp|
    smtp.send_message msgstr, 'from@server.com', 'to@server.com'
end
```

When I run this I get the following error.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:948:in `check_auth_continue': 
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:740:in `auth_login'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:921:in `critical'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:739:in `auth_login'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:725:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:725:in `authenticate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:566:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:463:in `start'
```

I can't find anything in the [Ruby api for Net::SMTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Net/SMTP.html) referencing TLS or a STARTTLS command.

**EDIT:
Download smtp-tls.rb, the code doesn't change much but here is what I got to work.**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/smtp'
require 'smtp-tls'

msgstr = <<MESSAGE_END
From: me <me@test.com>
To: you <you@test.com>
Subject: e-mail test

body of email

MESSAGE_END

smtp = Net::SMTP.start('smtp.test.com', 587, 'test.com', 'username', 'passwd', :login) do |smtp|
    smtp.send_message msgstr, 'me@test.com',  ['you@test.com']
end
```

**EDIT: Works with ruby 1.8.6**

Comment: The accepted answer is not correct (or at least, not anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net::SMTP doesn't look like it supports startTLS encryption. I did find a project on github that has code for dealing with this, though.

[smtp-tls](http://github.com/ambethia/smtp-tls/tree/master)

Answer (score 14):

## No gem required in Ruby 1.9.3

You don't need a gem to do this (at least, not for Gmail and Ruby 1.9.3), the documentation is just terrible.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3559598/4376

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get it working using your updated example. But the following did work for me.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'smtp_tls'
require 'net/smtp'

smtp = Net::SMTP.new 'smtp.gmail.com', 587
smtp.enable_starttls

smtp.start(Socket.gethostname,username,password,:login) do |server|
   server.send_message msg, from, to
end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I'm in 1.8.7 and get an "unknown method 'enable_starttls' error".  I've required smtp_tls and net/smtp.  One possible problem is that in my config i have `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp`.  Should this perhaps be set to something else eg smtp_tls or something?

Comment: I tried to install smtp_tls but I it said: `smtp_tls requires Ruby version ~> 1.8.6.0.`

Comment: and `smtp.enable_tls` for straight TLS instead of `smtp.enable_starttls`

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using the tlsmail gem:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'tlsmail'
require 'net/smtp'

Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
Net::SMTP.start(server,25,Socket.gethostname,username,password,:login) do |server|
  server.send_message msg, from, to
end
```

Comment: This was the winning formula for me with Ruby 1.9.3, but I made one change: I specified port 587 rather than port 25.