# git-commit-notifier with gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, githooks

First of all you have to know I'm total Ruby noob :)

I installed git-commit-notifier (http://github.com/ilozka/git-commit-notifier) on my system (Ubuntu 10.04) and followed all the installation instructions but every time I push to my git repository I get this error message:

```
remote: Sending mail...
remote: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:944:in `check_auth_response': 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. n20sm12555550ibe.5 (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError)
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:735:in `auth_plain'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:727:in `send'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:727:in `authenticate'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:568:in `do_start'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:527:in `start'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:465:in `start'
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/git-commit-notifier-0.7.2/bin/../lib/emailer.rb:42:in `perform_delivery_smtp'
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/git-commit-notifier-0.7.2/bin/../lib/emailer.rb:96:in `send'
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/git-commit-notifier-0.7.2/bin/../lib/commit_hook.rb:55:in `run'
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/git-commit-notifier-0.7.2/bin/../lib/diff_to_html.rb:285:in `each_with_index'
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/git-commit-notifier-0.7.2/bin/../lib/commit_hook.rb:51:in `each'
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/git-commit-notifier-0.7.2/bin/../lib/commit_hook.rb:51:in `each_with_index'
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/git-commit-notifier-0.7.2/bin/../lib/commit_hook.rb:51:in `run'
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/git-commit-notifier-0.7.2/bin/git-commit-notifier:13
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/git-commit-notifier:19:in `load'
remote:     from /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/git-commit-notifier:19
```

I tracked the error to emailer.rb script. Specifically line:

```
Net::SMTP.start(settings['address'], settings['port'], settings['domain'],                                                                                                                             
                settings['user_name'], settings['password'], settings['authentication']) do |smtp|
```

The parameters seemed to be passed correctly (i have checked that).

My config script looks like this:

```
# select the delivery method: smtp or sendmail
delivery_method: smtp

# settings for the smtp server
smtp_server:
    address: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    domain: mydomain
    user_name: redmine@mydomain.com
    password: xxxxxx
    authentication: plain
    enable_tls: true
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue? I have Redmine on the same server and it works fine. No problems with email sending.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Net::SMTP does not seem to support STARTTLS. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183743/ruby-getting-netsmtp-working-with-gmail) offers a solution to that problem by monkey-patching Net::SMTP to do just that.