# Why am I getting Net::SMTPSyntaxError?

Tags: ruby, email, smtp, gmail, sinatra

I am trying to set up a Sinatra based Ruby app to connect to Gmail and send emails through SMTP. I followed the instructions I found on the web, but I always get this error:

> Net::SMTPSyntaxError at /contact 502
>   5.5.1 Unrecognized command. k30sm7454901vbl.19
>
> ```
> * file: smtp.rb
> * location: check_response
> * line: 930
> ```

It's being raised from a core Ruby file

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb in check_response

...and here is the method in which it happens:

```
def check_response(res)
 unless res.success?

    raise res.exception_class, res.message

 end
end
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the actual code that you're using to try to send the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](http://www.jamesbritt.com/2007/12/18/sending-mail-through-gmail-with-ruby-s-net-smtp) might be helpful, where the author states that Google's SMTP demands the use of TLS which ruby's SMTP lib doesn't support out of the box. There's also a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183743/ruby-getting-netsmtp-working-with-gmail).